# Custom allocator with declared move operator leads to a segfault when used with gcc stl library

Tags: c++, c++11

Hello when using a custom allocator with a defined move operator, I am getting a segfault (with gcc but not with visual studio).

After having a look at the stl code, It appears that for some containers like deque, the stl move the allocator prior to the data tree destruction and leave the movable input to an "allocated state", leading to a segfault.

```
_Deque_base(_Deque_base&& __x, true_type)
      : _M_impl(std::move(__x._M_get_Tp_allocator()))
      {
    _M_initialize_map(0);
    if (__x._M_impl._M_map)
      this->_M_impl._M_swap_data(__x._M_impl);
      }
```

The problem is that the intitialisation of the datas on _M_initialize_map(0) allocate some objects (root node) and as the allocator is moved, on the destruction of the input object, the deallocation of this newly created node (swapped into the old object), is made with an invalid allocator as it has been moved previously.

So my question is, is it a bug of the implementation of the stl ? Or should a move operator of an allocator behave as a copy operator and not a "move" one ?

> Constructs a1 such that it equals the prior value of a. Does not throw
> exceptions. The value of a is unchanged and a1 == a. (since C++20)
>
> The value of a is unchanged and a1 == a. **(since C++20)**

As pointed out by the link of @{Some programmer dude}, since c++20, the move operator should behave as a copy operator on rvalue and not a true move operator one (why ?).

But there is no such mention for c++<20

Comment: The likelihood that the bug is in the standard library implementation and not in your code is very small. And perhaps [this allocator requirement reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) could be helpful?

Comment: thinks for the link

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] example?  Show the minimal allocator required to reproduce your problem, so we don't have to speculate about the origin of the problem.